# How to check if the email exists in Table Column in mySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How to Check if the email exists in MySQL...?

---

```
 

 public function AddReseller($name,$businessName,$businessPageName,$contactNumber,$fullAddress,$email)
    {
        $db = new Mysqlidb();
        if(!$db) die("Database error");

        $data = Array(
            'Name' => $name,
            'BusinessName' => $businessName,
            'Address' => $fullAddress,
            'ContactNumber'=>$contactNumber,
            'Email'=>$email,
            'PageName'=>$businessPageName
        );

        if($email > 0)
         {
            echo "Email Exists Already";
         }

        $id = $db->insert ('tenterprise', $data);
        return $id;
    }
```

This is the code and the $db-> is Insertion Query for table...!
Help me for this...! I am getting issue

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you are pretty bad on asking questions :) You are checking the $email parameter which you sent as a parameter to the function, but you want to check if that email is already in the database before you try to add this data array into the table. In that case it is obvious that you need a select query first on your table with using the sent parameter $email, something like this :

```
 $checkquery =   "select email from tenterprise where email = ".$email;
```

Than you should check if this query has any result. If it has this means you already have that email in your table, if result is empty, it means this email was not used before.

Try to be more specific on what you are trying to achive when you ask questions so others can focus on the correct thing to help you!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't hesitate to mark it as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code may look something like this. In order to get this work, you have to connect to database.

```
<?php 
$result =mysql_query("SELECT email FROM table WHERE `email` = 'test@sample.com'");
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
  echo 'Email Found'; 
}else{
  echo 'Email not Found'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using mysqlidb. with mysqlidb you can use where ()->get() to avoid writting sql.

```
public function AddReseller($name,$businessName,$businessPageName,$contactNumber,$fullAddress,$email)
        {
            $db = new Mysqlidb();
            if(!$db) die("Database error");

            $data = Array(
                'Name' => $name,
                'BusinessName' => $businessName,
                'Address' => $fullAddress,
                'ContactNumber'=>$contactNumber,
                'Email'=>$email,
                'PageName'=>$businessPageName
            );

            if($user = $db->where("email", $email)->get ('tenterprise')) > 0)
             {
                echo "Email Exists Already";
                return $user['id'];
             }

            $id = $db->insert ('tenterprise', $data);
            return $id;
        }
```